# Отваливается скрол при изменении doctype

Tags: javascript, html5, прокрутка

Всем привет!

Есть скрипт https://github.com/themicon/smoothscroll. 
Он осуществляет на сайте плавный скрол мышкой. При изменении `<!DOCTYPE>` на `<!DOCTYPE html>` полностью отваливается скролл.

Помогите, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в document.body.scrollTop (строки 81-83) https://github.com/themicon/smoothscroll/blob/master/smoothscroll.js

В функцию ssc_scrollArray (строка 80) добавить e=ssc_root:

```
    if (n) {  
        e=ssc_root;
        var m = e.scrollTop;
        e.scrollTop += u;
        if (u && e.scrollTop === m) {
            n = 0
        }
    }
```

и все заработает

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Мне помог ваш совет, еще раз спасибо, что помогли мне в этом деле!